# How to check for 2 variables in a single mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

Need some help in php mysql
suppose i am logged in as $active_username and I want to see all the messages between me($active_username) and my friend($username) from a table pvt_message, where i have columns(pid,user_from,user_to,body).
I tried using below code:

```
$getmessages= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pvt_messages WHERE user_from='$active_username' && user_to='$username' ORDER BY id ASC ") or die(mysql_error());

                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getmessages )) 
                        {
                            $body = $row['msg_body'];   
                            $date_send = $row['date'];
                            $opened = $row['opened'];
                            $get_user_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$active_username'");
                            $get_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_user_info);
                            $profilepic_info = $get_info['profile_pic'];
                            if ($profilepic_info == "") {
                             $profilepic_info = "./images/default_pic.jpg";
                            }
```

rest are the code to show data fetched on table, there is no error in that,so i didnt post.
this above code fetched me only those message i had sent to my friend.

again i used below code instead of above one:

```
$getmessages= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pvt_messages WHERE user_from='$active_username' && user_to='$username' ORDER BY id ASC ") or die(mysql_error());

                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getmessages )) 
                        {
                            $body = $row['msg_body'];   
                            $date_send = $row['date'];
                            $opened = $row['opened'];
                            $get_user_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$active_username'");
                            $get_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_user_info);
                            $profilepic_info = $get_info['profile_pic'];
                            if ($profilepic_info == "") {
                             $profilepic_info = "./images/default_pic.jpg";
                            }
```

n now it fetched me all those message he/she sent me.

I want to view message we both sent each other, in asending order of the primary key of the table.
so i tried using:

```
$getmessages= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pvt_messages WHERE (user_from='$active_username' || user_from='$username') && (user_to='$username' || user_to='$active_username') ORDER BY id ASC ") or die(mysql_error());

                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getmessages )) 
                        {
                            $body = $row['msg_body'];   
                            $date_send = $row['date'];
                            $opened = $row['opened'];
                            $get_user_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$active_username' || username ='$username'");
                            $get_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_user_info);
                            $profilepic_info = $get_info['profile_pic'];
                            if ($profilepic_info == "") {
                             $profilepic_info = "./images/default_pic.jpg";
                            }
```

how to get those data in table??? where user_from can be both me($active_username) or he($username) and user_to can be both me($active_username) or he ($username).
Thankyou in advance :)

Comment: what problem you are facing with the results ?

Answer (score 1):

Try it

`SELECT * FROM pvt_messages WHERE user_from IN ('$active_username', '$username') AND user_to IN ('$active_username', '$username')`

It will work if not have messages in DB from `active_username` to `active_username`

Answer (score 1):

just change your query like below

```
$getmessages= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pvt_messages WHERE ((user_from='$active_username' && user_to='$username') || (user_from='$username' && user_to='$active_username')) ORDER BY id ASC ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the below code before fetching from the user table and pass the `$qry` variable in the `mysql_query` function.

```
if($['user_from'] == $active_username)
{
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$active_username'";
}
else
{
    $qry ="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username'";
}

$get_user_info = mysql_query($qry);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get messages sequentially between my friend and me.... on basis of pid of the table pvt message using

```
$getmessages= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pvt_messages WHERE (user_from='$active_username' && user_to='$username') || (user_from='$username' && user_to='$active_username')  ORDER BY id ASC ") or die(mysql_error());

                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getmessages )) 
                        {
                            $body = $row['msg_body'];   
                            $date_send = $row['date'];
                            $opened = $row['opened'];
                            $get_user_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$active_username' || username='$username')");
                            $get_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_user_info);
                            $profilepic_info = $get_info['profile_pic'];
                            if ($profilepic_info == "") {
                             $profilepic_info = "./images/default_pic.jpg";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                             $profilepic_info = "./userdata/profile_pics/".$profilepic_info;
                            }
                            echo "
                                    <div style='float: left;padding-top:5px;'>
                                            <img src='$profilepic_info' height='20' width='20'>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style='padding-left:20px;padding-top:5px;'>
                                        <a href='$active_username'>Me:</a> $body
                                    </div></br>
                                    <div  style=' margin-left:80px;'>
                                     <br />
                                    </div>
                                    <hr />
                            ";
```

............. but now while i am fetching the user datas , to show name of user and profile pic too, only my pic is beling displayed in both my messages and my friend messages.
there is something wrong in line:

```
$get_user_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$active_username' || username='$username')");
```

Comment: i am trying something like facebook's messages page

Comment: print your query in database directly and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou everyone, for suggestion. I had to change a little bit, to get result I wanted.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getmessages )) 
                        {
                            $body = $row['msg_body'];   
                            $date_send = $row['date'];
                            $opened = $row['opened'];
                            $whosent= $row['user_from'];
                            $whoreceived= $row['user_to'];
                            $seen=$row['opened'];

                            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            $get_user_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$whosent')");
                            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            $get_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_user_info);
                            $profilepic_info = $get_info['profile_pic'];
                            if ($profilepic_info == "") {
                             $profilepic_info = "./images/default_pic.jpg";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                             $profilepic_info = "./userdata/profile_pics/".$profilepic_info;
                            }
                            echo "
                                    <div style='float: left;padding-top:5px; padding-left:20px;'>
                                            <img src='$profilepic_info' height='50' width='40'>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style='margin-left:50px;padding-top:5px;'>
                                        <a href='$active_username' style='color:black'> $whosent</a> $body
                                    </div></br>
                                    <div  style=' margin-left:30px;'>
                                    <font size='2px'>sent on: $date_send</font>
```